# How to modify default printscreen behaviour?

Tags: configuration, desktop-environments, screenshot, usability, print-screen

The <kbd>Prnt Scrn</kbd> button currently takes a screenshot and saves it in `~/Pictures`.

How can I modify the behaviour I want for the <kbd>Prnt Scrn</kbd> button?

Use case: I want to take a screenshot and go to GIMP and quickly use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the screenshot. If I do it now, I see:

```
GIMP Message
There is no image data in the clipboard to paste.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can copy a screenshot to clipboard by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>prt sc</kbd>. You can change this binding by going to *System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Screenshots*.

[image: Screenshot]