# Paste image resulted from Ctrl + Shift + PrintScreen

Tags: paste

when I try paste image resulted from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to freemind it don't paste anything.
But when I try paste it in LibreOffice, it works properly.
please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I have had similar problems.  Make sure that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> is still paste in that program.  You can try right click- paste, or the drop down menu (edit). I have experienced text editors in Linux where you have to use edit > paste, where hot keys were disabled.  Hope this helps.

Comment: none of the methods does not work :(

Comment: Could you paste it into libre office, copy it from libre office, and then paste it?   Try pasting any random picture.  Does that work?

Comment: yes, i can paste it into libre office, but it is not possible copy from libreoffice to free mind !!!, random pictures are same to image resulted from print screen. (paste into libreOffice but not pasting in freemind)

Comment: CAN you paste into freemind seams to be the better question.

Comment: no, i can't it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite a solution to the question as posed (and I realize this question is super old at this point!) but if you use <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>print screen</kbd> instead of <kbd>ctrk</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>print screen</kbd>, the image is saved to your Pictures directory (at least by default: see 
[How to modify default printscreen behaviour?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246099/how-to-modify-default-printscreen-behaviour) to check or change your settings).

That will create a `{timestamp}.png` file that you can import into an app, even if pasting the image from your clipboard does not work.